# 2 different code in single method, using Type maybe

Tags: c#

I have a bit of code like this,

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpMngr = newWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(newWeb.Url + "/default.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
      var wp = new WebPart1();
      wp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
      wpMngr.AddWebPart(wp, "left", 0);
}
```

and,

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpMngr = newWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(newWeb.Url + "/default.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
      var wp = new WebPart2();
      wp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
      wpMngr.AddWebPart(wp, "left", 0);
}
```

and so on... I have 10 code lines like this, how can I extract a method out of it ?

```
AddWebPart(SPWeb newWeb, string zone, Type what ?)
{
     not sure how to handle passing object WebPart1() and WebPart2 and so on...
}

AddWebPart(web, "left", WebPart1);
AddWebPart(web, "left", WebPart2);
```

Edit

All objects WebPartn will be of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart

Comment: Do `WebPart` 1 and 2 share a common base class / interface?

Answer (score 3):

If all WebPart share [WebPart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart(v=vs.110).aspx) as a common base class, then you could just do;

```
AddWebPart(SPWeb newWeb, string zone, WebPart webPart)
{
     webPart.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
     wpMngr.AddWebPart(webPart, "left", 0);
}

AddWebPart(web, "left", new WebPart1());
AddWebPart(web, "left", new WebPart2());
```

Note: this is only applicable if you're only calling methods that are part of the base class WebPart...again, assuming that is what you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You can create generic method for this and handle mutiple data types If i got you correctly overe here

solution is create generic method as given below

```
AddWebPart<T>(SPWeb newWeb, string zone, T webPart)
{
     not sure how to handle passing object WebPart1() and WebPart2 and so on...
}
```

Note : thre might be syntax error you can check on msdn about creating genric method.

---

If both are devried from same base class than you can also do like this:

```
AddWebPart(SPWeb newWeb, string zone, BaseWebPart webPart)
{
     not sure how to handle passing object WebPart1() and WebPart2 and so on...
}
```

BaseWebPart : here is base calss of webpart

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Test
{

    public class SPLimitedWebPartManager : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose() {                      }        
        internal void AddWebPart(WebPart wp,string p1,int p2) { }
    }

    public class WebPart
    {
        public object ChromeType { get; set;  }
    }

    public class WebPart1 : WebPart {}
    public class WebPart2 : WebPart {}

    internal class Program
    {

       public void AddWebPart( WebPart w)
       {
             using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpMngr = new SPLimitedWebPartManager() )
             {
                  var wp = w;
                  wp.ChromeType = "stuff";
                  wpMngr.AddWebPart(wp, "left", 0);
             }
        }
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.AddWebPart( new WebPart1() );
            p.AddWebPart( new WebPart2() );
        }
    }
}
```